# loading values from a variadic argument pack into a temporary array

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

This regrettably lengthy example is a cut-down version of a real piece of code I am attempting to write.  It has two problems.  First, as written, it doesn't compile: the error is

```
error: cannot bind ‘std::string’ lvalue to ‘std::string&&’
error:   initializing argument 3 of ‘void pack_arg(datum*, size_t, std::string&&)’
```

and is triggered by the presence of the call to `shut_the_door`.  If I take out the `&&` in the relevant overload of `pack_arg`, then it compiles, but the generated code appears to copy both strings, unnecessarily.  Second, I need to ensure that all string temporaries that the array `d` is holding pointers to, remain live until after the call to `vprocess`.  Right now the generated code appears to destruct them right before that call.

I am willing to consider quite radical changes to how the array is filled, as long as I have the opportunity to run each argument to `process` through an overloadable function call, independent of all the other such arguments.  (In particular, I suspect that the special rules for temporaries initializing a reference would make problem 2 go away if I could use `std::string&` in the union, but as each member of the `datum` array is filled in by assignment rather than initialization, that presently won't work, and I don't know how to make it be filled in by initialization without losing the calls to `pack_arg`, which are necessary in the larger context.)

**EDIT:** Using `std::forward` between `pack_args` and `pack_arg` does not appear to help; I get exactly the same error messages.

```
#include <string>
#include <stddef.h>
using std::string;

union datum
{
  const string* s;
  int i;
};

inline void
pack_arg(datum* d, size_t n, int t)
{
  d[n].i = t;
}

inline void
pack_arg(datum* d, size_t n, string && t)
{
  d[n].s = &t;
}

inline void
pack_args(datum*, size_t)
{
}

template <typename X, typename... XS> inline void
pack_args(datum* d, ::size_t n, X&& x, XS&&... xs)
{
  pack_arg(d, n, x);
  pack_args(d, n+1, xs...);
}

extern void vprocess(datum*, size_t);

template <typename... XS> inline void
process(XS&&... xs)
{
  size_t n = sizeof...(xs);
  datum d[n];
  pack_args(d, 0, xs...);
  vprocess(d, n);
}

extern string shut_the_door();

void
demo()
{
  process(1, 2, "buckle my shoe", 3, 4, shut_the_door());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luc brings a really interesting point (I briefly skimmed the code reading only the signatures):

If you are going to store pointers to the `std::string` in a container then your code *must* make sure that the arguments are **not** rvalues, as that will leave a dangling pointer after the function call completes.

The more I think on your code, the more I believe that the whole thing is just a bad idea. Without a tag on what each element is, you cannot know after the fact which element of the array is of what type. The lifetime of the objects will be hard to maintain (for the `std::string`s in particular...) Maybe you should rethink the design altogether.

---

You have hit an interesting quirk of the new C++11 syntax. The double ampersand (`&&`) in these two declarations don't really mean the same:

```
inline void
pack_arg(datum* d, size_t n, string && t);         // [1]
template <typename X, typename... XS> inline void
pack_args(datum* d, ::size_t n, X&& x, XS&&... xs) // [2]
```

In [1] the argument of type `string&&` will only bind to an rvalue allowing to discriminate a temporary (or `std::move`d object) from an lvalue. The *rvalue-reference* behaves like an lvalue inside the function. In [2], because you are in a template and `X` is an inferred type a different set of rules apply and `X&&` will be resolved to either an lvalue reference or rvalue reference, depending on the argument.

In your case, the argument is actually a temporary, so `X&&` will be mapped to `std::string&&`, but inside the function it is treated as an lvalue an cannot be bound. You can fix this by adding `std::forward`:

```
template <typename X, typename... XS> inline void
pack_args(datum* d, ::size_t n, X&& x, XS&&... xs)
{
  pack_arg(d, n, std::forward(x));
  pack_args(d, n+1, std::forward(xs)...);
}
```

The `std::forward` template will generate either an lvalue or rvalue reference depending on whether the argument is an lvalue or rvalue-reference itself.

Comment: I tried that (more precisely, I tried `std::forward<X>(x)`; without the `<X>` I get errors about failing to deduce the template argument) and got exactly the same error message.  (I meant to say so in the original post.  Sorry about that.)

Comment: If I understand what you're saying about [1] vs [2], though, perhaps I need to provide *both* `const string&` and `string&&` overloads of pack_arg?

Comment: @LucDanton: Uhm... that is an interesting point. Considering that the code is storing a pointer, it should not take the arguments with `&&` but rather with `const &`!!!

Comment: Assuming that `vprocess` doesn't store anything (transitively) and all of this is synchronous, there isn't very much of a problem. And if there is, value-category is not the right place to look -- for instance temporaries will still bind to ref to const anyway.

Comment: @Zack You only need to change `pack_arg` to accept `std::string const&` if `process` is intended to deal with lvalues (in which case an `std::string&&` overload would be superfluous, although not incorrect). If it isn't, you'd do well to make sure that `process` complains when called with an lvalue (e.g. with something like `static_assert( And<std::is_rvalue_reference<XS&&>...>::value, "Helpful error here" );`, although you have to roll your own `And`).

Comment: Just for clarity, there is a type tag in the non-cut-down version.  I'm afraid I have no idea what you mean about "*intended* to deal with lvalues".  `process` never *modifies* its arguments, but it has to accept all variations on `string` values, and should avoid copying them to the maximum extent possible.  When I had just a `string` overload with no reference modifiers, the generated code appeared to make a second copy of everything passed in.  Destructor timing is also an issue; it appears to fire them right *before* the call to `vprocess`, which is wrong and I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: @Zack: I shouldn't, but I tend to ignore most of the code when there is too much of it in a question... you should also use `std::forward` in the `process` function (basically anywhere where you want to maintain the l/r-valueness of the argument to your template). The concern above was about the `pack_args` outside of the context of `process`. If you pass an rvalue to `pack_args` with the code as initially shown in the answer (below the separator) the union inside `d` will hold a pointer to the temporary. The temporary will be destroyed after the call to `pack_args` leaving a dangling pointer.

Comment: Note that because the temporary is created outside of `process` and passed in, as Luc comments above, if `d` is not leaked outside of `process` it should be fine as the temporary will live up to the completion of the `process` function, and thus it will outlive the `pack_args`. On a side note, considering that you are storing *pointers* to the strings, I am not sure where the copy would be done if you just used lvalue references in all but the caller. I would have to work on the code for a while and I really don't have the time now.